# Where can you use “and/or”?

Tags: word-usage

I know that in formal contexts, the construction *and/or* is very ugly and undesirable (and there are many questions here that deal with said formal usage).

Has it become acceptable to use it informally, however, as a sort of rhetorical *faux* formalism or something else altogether?

Comment: What does "acceptable" mean here? Obviously people *do* use the form, both in speech and writing, so I think this is Not Constructive.

Comment: It's just poor style. Use it wherever you want, however, unless the style manual you must follow forbids it. Technical writers & other writers who don't care about writing ambiguously use it all the time. Biomedical articles are filled with such garbage lazyisms, as are the works of all hack academic writers. Informally, anything goes. Formally, the assigned style manual rules. Ultimately, however, the buck stops at the writer's fingers (OK, "input device"). Writers who respect words & language don't abuse them. The only time Medusa isn't ugly & petrifying is when she's invisible.

Comment: @BillFranke: *The only time Medusa isn't ugly is when she's invisible* is such a great comment, I wish my upvote helped your reputation. As it is, the best compliment I can pay you is to steal the phrase.

Comment: @Tim: Thank you. Be my guest. My reputation here's a mixed bag. Sometimes I'm up & sometimes I'm down. I often sabotage it as I build it. No matter. Reality's a mixed bag too. But it is nice to know that some folks like some of what I say. :-)

Comment: @TimLymington but if others then steal it from you, then we'll have to agree to remember where you got it so we can answer the question "What does the idiom 'medusa isn't ugly when she's invisible' come from?" in a few years' time.
I disagree with Bill on one point - writers who respect language might abuse them, but they will at least know when it's an abuse.

Comment: Since everyone else here seems to be agreeing that *and/or* is "poor style", I'll just post this comment to say I don't see anything wrong with it in most contexts. It's a lot simpler than trying to find other ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: @BillFranke Come to Chat and I'll say nice things about it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style [section 5.220] has this to say:

> **and/or**. Avoid this Janus-faced term. It can often be replaced by *and* or *or* with no loss in meaning. Where it seems needed [take a sleeping pill and/or a warm drink], try *or . . . or both* [take a
>   sleeping pill or a warm drink or both]. But think of other
>   possibilities [take a sleeping pill with a warm drink].

There are always more graceful ways to phrase a sentence without resorting to *and/or*.

Comment: What I mean is, if I'm specifically aiming for that sort of trip-on-your-laces feel, could I use it?

Comment: @Joe Zeng: If you're happy to use terms like *trip-on-your-laces feel*, I think you can probably use *and/or*. At least the latter has the advantage of being generally understood, which I can't believe applies to the former.

Comment: Strangely, I can hear it being used in a sentence of breezy informality, or to lend a sense of faux pomposity (to wit, voiced by the sort of character who would use the phrase "to wit").

Comment: Joe, you mean you want to create an impression of pomposity for a windbag character or something? Heavy use could definitely help that, especially if the cases are such that the context makes it particularly clear - or better yet, makes the either the *and* or the *or* part of it an impossibility ("planning to go into space and/or to the moon").

Comment: Pomposity might not be the right word. I think Gnawme's "breezy informality" says it better.

Answer (score 2):

It's appropriate in a technical or legal context (which would often be a type of formal context), where the precision of indicating that you mean "X or Y or (X and Y)" is desirable.

"X or Y" can be validly interpreted as "X or Y or (X and Y)" or as "X or Y but not (X and Y)". Mostly we get by judging which is meant from context, but in legal and technical contexts such misinterpretation could be costly, if not disastrous.

Such contexts also tend to be explicit in the other direction - if they mean "X or Y but not both" they will make sure to include that "...but not both". They may also emphasis an **either** and an **or** with bolding or similar.

Such contexts are "formal" by some standards, but different to some other types of formal prose, in which it should probably not be used. This can include different passages in the same work: It may be appropriate in an item list giving a break-down of a process, but not appropriate in accompanying paragraphs.

In informal use, you can of course do whatever you want. Such use would be rather slangy, and like all slang some people will like it and some will not.

Comment: Do you have a source to support that *X or Y* does not include *X and Y*? You describe what is generally known as [*exclusive or*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). The [inclusive version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), formally known as *inclusive disjunction*, informally known simply as *or* does include *X and Y*.

Comment: @JJJ No, because I didn't say that.

Comment: You wrote (emphasis is mine): *"X or Y" **can be validly interpreted** as "X or Y or (X and Y)" or as "X or Y but not (X and Y)".* To me that seems you say it's valid to interpret *or* as the *exclusive or*.

Comment: @JJJ Ah, I thought you were saying that I was saying that that was the only valid interpretation. Calling *exclusive or*, *exclusive or* also implies that it's valid to interpret *or* as *exclusive or*, since it uses *or* as the main term and the qualifier *exclusive* to clarify which among a choice of possibilities is intended

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And/or) in Wikipedia:

> And/or (also and or) is a grammatical conjunction used to indicate that one or more of the cases it connects may occur. For example, the sentence "He will eat cake, pie, and/or brownies" indicates that although the person may eat any of the three listed desserts, the choices are not exclusive; the person may eat one, two, or all three of the choices.

As you said you can easily use that informally,  but you can also use it in formal conditions, where it makes sense. But I think maybe "either" is the best choice for such situations.